# JISON Recursion To read entire input text after a Token

Tags: parsing, bison, context-free-grammar, jison

I'm very much new to parser/cfg or jison. What I want my grammar to do is:

1. Read everything after Token ADDRESS to EOF
2. There can be multiple ADDRESS tokens between "ADDRESS TO EOF"(from step 1)

My sample input looks like :

```
...abc xyz address 101 My Street, Austin, CO 12345 is abc xyz my name is govind my address is 102 My Street,Austin, CO 12345 and here it is end of file.
```

The output I'm expecting is

```
address 101 My Street, Austin, CO 12345 is abc xyz my name is govind my address is 102 My Street,Austin, CO 12345 and here it is end of file.`
```

The code I'm trying is

```js
/* lexical grammar */

%lex
%options flex

%{
if (!('chars' in yy)) {
   yy.temp = 0;
}


%}
%%
\s+                   /* skip whitespace */ 
(address|Address)      return 'ADDRESS'
<<EOF>>                return 'EOF'
[A-Za-z0-9]+           return 'VARIABLE'
.                     /*skip */

/lex

%start expressions
%% /* language grammar */

expressions
   : other EOF
    {return $1;}

   ;

other
  :VARIABLE{$$=$1;}  
  |other ADDRESS other {$$=$1+"-"+$2+"-"+$3;} 
  ;
```

What I think there should be few more expression to achieve the output as `other ADDRESS other` is throwing S/R conflict. Can anyone suggest me that how can I skip all the inputs before occurrence of first `ADDRESS` token and than put all other inputs in `$$`.
Thanks.

Comment: This is really not the sort of problem that you would normally want to solve with a parser generator.

Answer (score 1):

As a general principle, when you want to recognize only the first *X* in a list of *X* or *Y*, you need something like this:

```
list: head X tail;
tail: | tail X | tail Y;
head: | head Y;
```

Here `head` matches any number (including 0) of *Y* and `tail` matches any number (including 0) of either *X* or *Y*. Consequently, the *X* matched by `list` must be the first *X* in the input, and there is no ambiguity.

The `tail` non-terminal here is unnecessary in this case, but it is often useful to produce a correct parse tree. You could write the above grammar:

```
list: head X | list X | list Y;
head: | head Y;
```

If you also wanted to match lists without any *X*, you could add the production `list: head`:

```
list: head | head X tail;
tail: | tail X | tail Y;
head: | head Y;
```

Comment: not exactly the one I was looking for but it helped me to solve my other problem :) Thanks..